# Getting a substring from a string starting after a particular character

Tags: php, imap

i was using this code at present 
it works when the imap subject received as

"code.115 is your id"

`$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection, $e);
            if (!strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code.$id")) {
            echo true 
                        }`

But some times the imap subject will be received as

"code. 115 is your id"

i tried using below one but didnt worked.

`$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection, $e);
            if (!strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code./\s/$id")) {
            echo true 
                        }`
Any help provided is really appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: `strpos` doesn't accept regex identifiers such as `\s`, try doing `if (!strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code. $id") && !strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code.$id")) {`

Comment: Didnt worked that one too.

Comment: Can i do this with preg_match?

Comment: Yes, `preg_match` might work, try this: `if (!preg_match($headerInfo->subject, "/code\. ?$id/")) {`